Pricing for AWS VPC Public IPv4 Addresses
I created a RDS with Public Accessable flag set to true and connected it to public subnet of default VPC.
Then I realized that AWS charged me for Public IPv4 Addresses under the VPC section.
You can see billing page

Is it something related to connecting a service to VPC?
Also can I use something else instead of Public IPv4 Addresses to avoid this cost?

To be publicly accessible it must have an external IP. You'd need a non-publicly accessible RDS to avoid the IPv4 cost.

Investigate using an IPV6 address?

AWS introduced a new charge for public IPv4 addresses. Effective February 1, 2024 there will be a charge of $0.005 per IP per hour for all public IPv4 addresses, whether attached to a service or not (there is already a charge for public IPv4 addresses you allocate in your account but don’t attach to an EC2 instance).
You can find more information here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-public-ipv4-address-charge-public-ip-insights/
You can also review optimization suggestions on IPv4 like:
Consider disabling the auto-assignment of public IPv4 addresses on default subnets. For example, subnets that host your Amazon ECS deployments, or RDS databases, may not need public IPv4 addresses.
If disabling auto-assignment of public IPv4 addresses at the subnet level is not an option, consider changing the auto-assignment of public IP addresses during instance launch. Overriding the subnet’s public IP addressing attribute allows you to control the level of granularity when resources receive public IPv4 addresses
For remote access to resources within your VPCs, consider using Amazon EC2 Instance Connect (EIC) Endpoints instead of assigning public IPv4 addresses to each resource. This will help you optimize the number of public IPv4 addresses associated with your resources and improve your security posture.
Read here for more information
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/identify-and-optimize-public-ipv4-address-usage-on-aws/
Good luck!
